# Trying to get Facebook API but get redirected back to my Page

Tags: facebook

I need an API key from Facebook, but every time I try to get go to facebook.com/developers while logged into my account I get redirected back to my Facebook page.

How do I get a Facebook API key without this bouncing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

If this doesn't work, perhaps you should try logging out, clearing your cache, cookies and then log in again?